# Hive how to load data into partitioned table from unpartitioned table with where condition

Tags: hiveql

- samp1 table is a partitioned on the year and month columns
- The data is stored in the ORCFile format
- Insert the records from January, 2008, of the samp2 table into the
  appropriate partition of weather_partitione

d

Answer (score 1):

INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE dest_table_name PARTITION (year, month) SELECT all other columns,year,month FROM source_table_name;
When using dynamic partitions, partition columns should come as the last columns in the select query.